# how to write correctly into multidimentional char array unknown amount of values but fixed amound of chars

Tags: c++, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm sick and tired of solving why my ch[0] is of value "Thomas EdisonÇ@", when it should be "Thomas Edison"

```
int main(){
using namespace std;
ifstream in("U2.txt");
int n;
in>>n; //n=rows, so in every line there will be "name surname", time, money

char ch[n][21]; //I'm trying to get Name+Surname which must be 20 char long
in.read(ch[0], 20);
cout << ch[0]; //but getting Thomas EdisonÇ@
return 0;}
```

It works on one dimentional ch[21], but there's gonna be lots of values so I want to use ch[n][21]

Any other out of my box solution is welcome, I'm tired

Comment: This is not valid C++ (VLAs). Use vectors and strings.

Comment: using null terminator was solution to have clear value(not Thomas EdisonÇ@), however ch[n][20] didn't have n values as expected, so I used string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting that C strings need to be nul terminated

```
in.read(ch[0], 20);
ch[0][20] = '\0'; // add the nul terminator
cout << ch[0];    // now correct output
```